# Filter in Many2one

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I need Many2one field only show names that are in a specific group.
For example:
 show all members from group purchase_managers in drop down.
 Please help me =)

I have
.py

```
assigned_to = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Approver', 
                              track_visibility='onchange')
```

view

```
 <field name="assigned_to"
                               attrs="{'readonly': [('is_editable','=', False)]}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can handle it in *.py* file with *domain* attribute.

```
domain=[('field_name', 'operator', value)])
```

Try with following code:

```
assigned_to = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Approver', 
          track_visibility='onchange', domain=[('is_editable', '=', True)])
```

Result:

It will load data which User has *is_editable* checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `domain` attribute in the view:

```
<field name="assigned_to" domain="[('is_editable','=', True)]" />
```